# Java Generate Soap Envelop Message With Same Element Name With Different Type

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am new to web services. i am writing soap web services. Below is my bean structure which i wrote in web service.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="processRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(value=XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RequestDO {

    @XmlElement(name="command", type=Common.class)
    private List<Common> commonList = null;

    @XmlElement(name="command",type=Output.class)
    private List<Output> outputList = null;

    public List<Common> getCommonList() {
        return commonList;
    }

    public void setCommonList(
            List<Common> commonList) {
        this.commonList = commonList;
    }

    public List<PremiumInputCalcDO> getOutputList() {
        return outputList;
    }

    public void setOutputList(
            List<Output> commonList) {
        this.commonList = commonList;
    }

}
```

When i use wsimport to generate client stub then it says **Multiple elements with same name 'command'**. But my Soap envelop message should be like below.

```
<S:Envelope> <S:Body>
// List of common fields will be here
<command xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsCommand">
            <field>DATE</field>
            <value>20170101</value>
         </command>

// List of output/result fields will be here
<command xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsCommandResp">
            <txnAmt>100.00</txnAmt>
         </command>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I need to add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsCommand" & xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:wsCommandResp" to the elements.

Please help me by providing suggestion.